# URL is being terminated on browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string

This is my link in that im sending query string but while clicking that url

```
&uid=a49ce59f-7606-4d22-a8b0-53d4696c1784
```

this part is not coming in url bar

original link

This is my code where im creating hyperlink

```
http://demo.check.in/Login.aspx?ipAddress=199.82.182.31&uid=a49ce59f-7606-4d22-a8b0-53d4696c1784
```

in url bar im getting this

```
http://demo.check.in/Login.aspx?ipAddress=199.82.182.31
```

why the half part is not going in url bar from & symbol

```
<p><a href="http://demo.check.in/Login.aspx?ipAddress=<%VisitorsIPAddr%>">http://demo.check.in/Login.aspx?ipAddress=<%VisitorsIPAddr%>&uid=<%guid%></a></p>
```

Comment: Show the code from where this is generated.

Comment: i just want to send ip address and one guid to url bar for confirmation. im sending full link to mail . but while clicking on that ljnk in the mail . only half part is not coming and saying "Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier."@MairajAhmad

Comment: That is what we are asking. Show the code for "im sending full link to mail"

Comment: may be you're creating proper link as string, but not in the anchor tag's `href`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `<a href>` tag is missing the "&uid=<%guid%>" portion.

**Before**

```
<p><a href="http://demo.check.in/Login.aspx?ipAddress=<%VisitorsIPAddr%>">http://demo.check.in/Login.aspx?ipAddress=<%VisitorsIPAddr%>&uid=<%guid%></a></p>
```

**After**

```
<p><a href="http://demo.check.in/Login.aspx?ipAddress=<%VisitorsIPAddr%>&uid=<%guid%>">http://demo.check.in/Login.aspx?ipAddress=<%VisitorsIPAddr%>&uid=<%guid%></a></p>
```

Comment: Thats what I commented earlier that he's creating only `innerHtml` not the `href`